# The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController how to handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched in many other threads, but nothing realy helped me out. So i have implemented a comment function with polymorphy so that everybody is able to comment on every comment. My problem is that if i create a comment he is asking for a show method.

**My log says**

```
Started POST "/comments/59/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-07 21:15:40 
+0100
 Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? 
 ORDER 
 BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE 
 "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 59], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    (0.5ms)  begin transaction
   Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE 
  "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 59], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "created_at", "updated_at", 
 "user_id", "commentable_id", "commentable_type") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
 [["body", "huihuihuihuihuihio"], ["created_at", "2018-01-07 
 20:15:40.254229"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-07 20:15:40.254229"], 
 ["user_id", 1], ["commentable_id", 59], ["commentable_type", "Comment"]]
    (89.3ms)  commit transaction
    (0.0ms)  begin transaction
    (0.0ms)  commit transaction
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/comments/60
 Completed 302 Found in 118ms (ActiveRecord: 91.3ms)


 Started GET "/comments/60" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-07 21:15:40 +0100

 AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found 
 for CommentsController):
```

**My routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do 
  resources :comments 
end

resources :comments do
  resources :comments
end
```

**My comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_commentable


def new
    @comment=Comment.new
end


def create 
    @comment =@commentable.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body).merge(user: current_user))
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to comment_path(@comment), notice: 'Dein Kommentar wurde gespeichert'
    else
        redirect_to comment_path(@comment), notice: 'Dein Kommentar konnte leider nicht gespeichert werden, ueberpruefen sie ihre Eingaben'
    end
end

private

def find_commentable
    @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
    @commentable = Post.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:post_id]
end
end
```

**My comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

To be honest i have the same Problem with deleting my posts and the posts_controller.rb.There i "fixed" it with giving the show method the same code as my delete method.
So if you have an idea or need more code pls let me know

**EDIT**
**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user, optional: true
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy

validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
validates :body, presence: true

 has_attached_file :image  #, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => 
"100x100>" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Post_controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  if current_user
  @post.user_id = current_user.id
end
  @post= Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  else
     render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  redirect_to posts_path
end

private

def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :theme)
end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't have a `show` action in your Comments controller yet you are saying `redirect_to comment_path(@comment)` which is asking the server for the default path of "/comments/60". You resourced your routes so the server is expecting that route to equal the show action. You should view all of your routes so you better understand what is happening. The idea of convention over configuration is the assumption of these defaults until you override them. What did you expect to happen when you `redirect_to comment_path(@comment)` ?

Try this path in your browser, inserting your app name:

```
http://localhost/your_app_name/rails/info/routes.
```

This will show you what the server is expecting. You can add the results to your question if you need explanation. But basically you need to add that action to your controller, or tell the controller to render something else when the action completes. What do you WANT to see after that action completes?

If you don't want a `show` action you could do:

```
redirect_to post_path(@comment.commentable_id)
```

As has become clear from below, you did not have a `show` action for your Post Controller. It appears from the code you added that you have done this? Also if the `redirect...` I suggested above does not work because there is no `post_id` associated with `@comment` then you have other deeper problems. Most of you problems are stemming from the fact that you are using standard things like

```
resources :posts do 
  resources :comments 
end
```

But then doing non-standard things like not having the standard CRUD actions for each controller. Yes you can skip somethings you don't need but the point of Rails is to help make things easier with convention over configuration.

**EDIT**

Changed `post_id` to `commentable_id` because that is how it is referred to in your code. This may work but since you are allowing comments on comments it might not. Basically if a comment belongs to a comment that belongs to a Post, then you have to traverse that tree upwards or just go to the index page like you chose to.

Comment: I dont want a show method in this controller, because i render the comments into my post.show.html.erb.  `redirect_to comment_path(@comment)` was a desperate try after `redirect_to post_path(@post)` also asked for a show method. but how can i fix this ?

Comment: 1. i tryed your path with my appname but its not reachable :( 2. After the action i want to see the post.show with the correct post_id in which the comment was written. thats why i tried `@post =Post.find(params[:post_id])` and `redirect_to post_path(@post)`

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: `@post` is probably not available in the context you are trying to use it. You could try `redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id)`

Comment: Add show action in postscontroller as @post =Post.find(params[:id])

Comment: Also since you are doing a lot of non-standard things you need to show your models for `Posts` and `Comments` so I'm not guessing at everything.

Comment: @Lavika that is a possible solution but they have not shown thier controller code for that and they are showing `Posts` somehow so they must have code that does the work. So the question needs to have the controller coded added.

Comment: @Beartech Agree. He mentions in one of the above comments that he tried redirecting to post show page but failed. He was doing 

`@post =Post.find(params[:post_id])`

I corrected that.

Comment: I am using rails 5.1.4. So i tried it with redirecting to my posts_path (index page) and this is working. I also tried @Beartech s idea `redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id)`  but this gives me a `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]` error. i will edit my post model and post controller

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and your explanations. You are right with the point of redirecting with commentable_id is not quite possible since you can comment on a comment of a comment...i will try to find a solution for that one. And i didnt posted every method because they did not refer to the problem

Comment: You could keep some sort of post_id reference that is the ultimate parent but you will also be running into some serious n+1 issues. There is a good reason most blogs only allow commenting to a certain depth so they don't get comments that are pushed so far to the right indenting that they are one letter wide, though some do exactly that and it looks terrible and is completely unreadable.

Comment: i see your point, maybe i will just copy the comment_controller/model etc. call it undercomment and instead of making associations to post i will make some to comment. But thats not really dry

Comment: True. Better to pass down the post_id in some way. That shouldn't be hard since any first level comment would have that post_id as commentable_id. Add post_id column to your DB schema, then save that in any first level comment. You can then pass it on to any comments of comments.